# Acceptance test breaks my model unit test suite, ember-cli 0.44

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Here's how to reproduce. Using `ember-cli` 0.44, create a new app, and generate a `user` and `address` model. They each `belongsTo` each other.

Then, write a unit test for the `address` that looks like this:

```
test('it has a user', function() {
  var model = this.subject();
  var store = this.store();

  Ember.run(function() {
    var user = store.createRecord('user');
    model.set('user', user);

    ok(true);
  });
});
```

adding `needs: ['model:user']` to the test. The test passes.

Now, type `ember g acceptance-test index`. The unit tests break for the model, right on the `model.set` line:

```
Died on test #1     at test (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:278:13)
    at eval (ember-wtf/tests/unit/models/address-test.js:21:5)
    at requireModule (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70:29)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-loader.js:14:29: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship
Source:     
Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26705:23)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16889:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70696:17)
    at Descriptor.ComputedPropertyPrototype.set (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:25311:22)
    at set (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:30004:14)
    at __exports__.default.Mixin.create.set (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:44299:9)
    at eval (ember-wtf/tests/unit/models/address-test.js:29:15)
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:13365:27)
    at apply (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:31547:27)
```

---

Any ideas? Is `store.createRecord` not allowed in unit tests?

References:

- [Testing relationships](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-models/#toc_testing-relationships)

Comment: Whats the test runner output?

Comment: @papirtiger I dug through the trace a bit. The `store` from my test was not the same as the one used within `ember-data` to make the assertion. So `user instanceof store.modelFor('user')` is true with my store, but not the one used in the lib.

Comment: I wonder if the acceptance test causes a different store to be instantiated first, and if simply need to keep all tests involving the store within acceptance tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the store references were different, and even though `this.store()` seems like the blessed way to retrieve the store, it's a different from what was used to make `model`:

```
var model = this.subject();

model.store.toString();  //<DS.Store:ember816>
this.store().toString(); //<DS.Store:ember817>
```

So, when I tried to use `model.set('relationship'..`, Ember didn't think it was coming from the same store, and the assertion failed.

Using `model.store` seems to do the trick.

---

I believe this is bug in the `this.store` test helper.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running a similar test in a non-CLI app (Teaspoon 0.8.0, QUnit 1.14.0, Ember.js 1.7.0) and I don't run into the same issue. Both ways of accessing the store result in the same store object.

Comment: You also have acceptance tests? What version of ember-qunit?

Comment: I also have acceptance tests (do you mean the same as integration tests?) but they do not create models in the store directly. I use the latest release of ember-qunit, i.e. 0.1.8 (https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/tree/v0.1.8).

Comment: Did you file an ember-cli bug for this?

Comment: No, spent a bit of time looking for the appropriate place + looking for a test, but couldn't find one. I need to though.

Comment: Hi Sam, I am currently migrating the Hstry application to ember-cli and I encountered the exact same problem as you. I could solve it with your fix (thanks for figuring it out!) but I was wondering if you have any updates on it being fixed in Ember itself? I think `this.store()` and `this.subject().store` are not meant to be different, I'm pretty sure it's a bug. Do you know if it's been brought up as an issue on GitHub in the meantime?

Comment: @yorbro I believe last time I checked, they referred to the same thing. What version of CLI are you on?

Comment: @SamSelikoff I'm on 0.1.11.

Comment: Hm. I never got around to filing an issue, I couldn't find out where. I think it has to do with one of the ember qunit libs?

Comment: @SamSelikoff I'm not sure where the bug could lie, it might be an ember-cli thing as well. Since I'm not sure, I posted an issue on the Ember.js tracker (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10367).

Answer (score 0):

For newest versions of ember-cli, Ember and Ember-data this problem is not happening. Github issue is close also https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-qunit/issues/42